# Loop and display substring in python

Tags: python

I wanted to display more than one substring from a string.

Raw string:
`<td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong>Mar08</strong></td><td><strong>Mar09</strong></td><td><strong>Mar10</strong></td><td><strong>Mar11</strong></td><td><strong>Mar12</strong></td><td><strong>Mar13</strong></td></tr>`

To display, expected result[Substring] :

`Mar08 
 Mar09
 Mar10
 Mar11
 Mar12
 Mar13`

I've tried with this code

```
def parseyear(list):
    sfind = "<strong>"
    efind = "</strong>"
    i = 0
    while i < len(list):
        s =  list.find(sfind,i,len(list))
        e = list.find(efind,s,len(list))
        v = list[s+len(sfind):e]
        i =  i + s
        print v
```

But it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: This looks like HTML. Consider using an HTML parser?

Comment: I don't see any difference between input and output

Comment: @AhsanulHaque please find the edited version .

Comment: Oops, was just trying to adjust formatting a little. Sorry!

Comment: @ChrisMartin Thank you, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `regex`:

```
>>> for m in re.findall(r'<strong>([^<]+)</strong>', raw_string):
...     print m
... 
Mar08
Mar09
Mar10
Mar11
Mar12
Mar13
```

Comment: (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: When I tried to do the same for following raw text, it doesn't work <td><strong>0.00</strong></td><td><strong>0.00</strong></td><td><strong>0.00</strong></td><td><strong>0.21</strong></td><td><strong>0.23</strong></td><td><strong>1.23</strong></td><td><strong>1.30</strong></td><td><strong>1.74</strong></td><td><strong>0.87</strong></td><td><strong>0.98</strong></td></tr>

Comment: Now you have two problems.

Comment: Just refine the ``regex`` @jOSe. See my ed answer

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use regex:

```
def find_substrings(s, delim_start, delim_end):
    """Find the string that is delimited by two different strings."""
    start = s.find(delim_start)
    # to calculate the length of the start delimiter
    len_delim_start = len(delim_start)
    while start != -1:
        end = s.find(delim_end, start + 1)
        substring = s[(start + len_delim_start):end]
        # print only if substring is not empty
        if substring: print substring
        start = s.find(delim_start, end + 1)

html = """
<td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong>
</td><td><strong>Mar08</strong></td><td><strong>Mar09</strong></td><td><strong>Mar10</strong></td>
<td><strong>Mar11</strong></td><td><strong>Mar12</strong></td><td><strong>Mar13</strong></td></tr>
"""

html2 = """
<td><strong>0.00</strong></td><td><strong>0.00</strong></td><td><strong>0.00</strong></td><td>
<strong>0.21</strong></td><td><strong>0.23</strong></td><td><strong>1.23</strong></td><td><strong>
1.30</strong></td><td><strong>1.74</strong></td><td><strong>0.87</strong></td><td><strong>
0.98</strong></td></tr>
"""

find_substrings(html2, "<strong>", "</strong>")

# output:
# 0.00
# 0.00
# 0.00
# 0.21
# 0.23
# 1.23
# 1.30
# 1.74
# 0.87
# 0.98
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using xml parser, given known xml data structure.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree 
s = "<tr><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong></strong></td><td><strong>Mar08</strong></td><td><strong>Mar09</strong></td><td><strong>Mar10</strong></td><td><strong>Mar11</strong></td><td><strong>Mar12</strong></td><td><strong>Mar13</strong></td></tr>"
parsed_xml = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(s)
values = [e.text for e in parsed_xml.findall("./td/strong") if e.text]
assert values == ['Mar08', 'Mar09', 'Mar10', 'Mar11', 'Mar12', 'Mar13']
```